# How can compound a exponential distribution with gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions, compound-distributions

A random variable X is said to have a exponential distribution with parameter lamda > 0. if its pdf is given by f(x,lamda)=(lamda * exp(-lamda * x)).
A random variable X is said to have a gamma distribution with parameter lamda > 0. if its pdf is given by f(x) = (exp(-lamda) * x^(lamda -1))/gamma(lamda).
How to find the compound of above two distributions.

Comment: 1. Use latex for writing mathematical equations see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
2. Gamma Distribution has 2 parameters, you're mentioning only 1, please check & edit your question accordingly. Refer: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/15/15.6
3. Some minor grammer corrections are needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "finding" the compound? Do you want to write down the PDF of the compound? Do you want to fit a compound, given observations?

Comment: Also, does this question at Math.SE do what you want? [compound of gamma and exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/646852/51074) (Found by simply [searching for "exponential gamma compound"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=exponential+gamma+compound))